# Why is writing Excel cell values fast in VBScript but slow in PowerShell?

Tags: excel, optimization, powershell, vbscript, powershell-2.0

Why is it that writing cell values to Excel is a lot faster in VBScript than in PowerShell?
Isn't PowerShell the new thing, and VBScript the deprecated MS scripting language?

**VBScript example (save to filename.vbs)**
This runs in a split second.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = false
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()

' Edit: increased number of writes to 500 to make speed difference more noticeable
For row = 1 To 500
     'Edit: using .cells(row,1) instead of .cells(50,1) - this was a mistake
     objWorkbook.workSheets(1).cells(row,1).value = "test"
Next

objWorkbook.SaveAs(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName) & "\test.xlsx")
objExcel.Quit
msgbox "Done."
```

**PowerShell example (save to filename.ps1)** This takes multiple seconds to run (problematic on thousands of records)

```
#need this to work around bug if you use a non-US locale: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;320369
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US" 

$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $False
$xls_workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

# Edit: using foreach instead of for
# Edit: increased number of writes to 500 to make speed difference more noticeable
foreach ($row in 1..500) {
    # Edit: Commented out print-line, slows down the script
    #"Row " + $row
    # This is very slow! - http://forums.redmondmag.com/forums/forum_posts.asp?tid=4037&pn=7
    $xls_workbook.sheets.item(1).cells.item($row,1) = "test"
}

$xls_workbook.SaveAs($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition.Replace($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name, "") + "test.xlsx")
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
```

I want to use this for thousands of records. If there is no fast way to do this, PowerShell is not an option. Are there better alternatives?

Comment: more "Power" usually comes with more resource needs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343413/vbs-vs-powershell-which-is-lighter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can speed things up by not looping through individual cells:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $True
$xls_workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

$range = $xls_workbook.sheets.item(1).Range("A1:A100")
$range.Value2 = "test"
```

If you want to write an array of values to a range, here is a nice blog post that demonstrates similar technique:

[How to Get Data into an Excel Spreadsheet Very Quickly with PowerShell](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/how-to-get-data-into-an-excel-spreadsheet-very-quickly-with-powershell-contd/)

Comment: Ok, I'll guess the Link to the Array-Attempt made this the solution, but I would really like to know, if PS is faster with it, compared to an array-solution in VB. @Wouter - would be nice, if you could post some new comparing results.

Comment: Although not really the answer to the question, i'm going to mark it as accepted answer. It accomplishes what i wanted to do; writing fast, to Excel, from PowerShell.

I'm going to assume writing cell by cell is somehow "not the way to do it" in PowerShell, while it worked in VBScript. It seems like a step back in usability for PowerShell vs VBScript. If anyone has an explanation for the speed difference, feel free to let me know!

Comment: @Jook - I've tested the Range-method with up to 1.000.000 writes in PS and VBS, in both cases it takes about 3 seconds, so the time difference, if any, is negligible. Also, it shows that the Range-method is also the better method to use in VBScript, since it would take ages with the Cell-method.

Answer (score 4):

some things don't add up here:

your VBScript, writes on ONE cell over and over, while your PowerShell code writes into 100 cells

```
objWorkbook.workSheets(1).cells(50,1).value = "test"

$xls_workbook.sheets.item(1).cells.item($row,1) = "test"
```

you are executing `"Row " + $row` on PowerShell - this might offset comparison too.

If you want to write into multiple cells, you should think about using arrays and wrinting onto whole ranges, because this has better performance.

Comment: I haven't run the VBScript version, but with 100 records the `"Row " + $row` output adds about a half second (total runtime was under 5 seconds for me).

Comment: you should run the VBScript version properly - filling single cells is a performance killer under VB too - on my machine this took about a second - without the saving part (i7@3,4GHz 8GB Ram).

Comment: Running the corrected VBS (using `row` instead of `50`), I got 1.391 seconds - 3X faster than the PowerShell version.

Comment: Hey Jook, sorry, the (50, 1) was a mistake, that indeed had to be ($row, 1). 

I've also increased the number of rows to 500 to make the speed difference more obvious. On my system, with the current script, VBS finishes in about a second, and PS in 20 seconds. With 10.000 rows, vbs finishes in 9 seconds. I don't want to know how long it would take in PS...

Comment: now that are some results ;) I am sorry, but I don't know much about PS to help you any further; +1 for your question though, cause you got me quite interested in the solution to this.

Comment: 6m 15s to run in PowerShell w/ 10K iterations. Quad Core i7 w/ hyperthreading, I saw about 9% CPU utilization, which would be about right - Excel going as fast as it can.

Answer (score 1):

You can shave a little time off the PowerShell version by eliminating the `for` loop test and using a `foreach`.

```
for ($row = 1; $row -le 100; $row++)
```

goes to:

```
foreach ($row in 1..100)
```

By doing this you eliminate the comparison and increment.

But aside from that, my observations match yours (see my comments on Jook's answer).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yet, it seems to be only a marginal speed improvement, if any.

Comment: It has been proven time and time again that for is faster than foreach. I'm sure this is no different in powershell...so it would be a marginal DECREASE in speed heh...

Answer (score 0):

You're still interfacing with Excel through COM though.  That's adding some overhead due to COMInterop processing.

Comment: Is the VBScript not also using a COM object?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell, by its very design and use of cmdlets is a non-standard mess, at least for basic things.  VBScript, which any programmer should be able to use and understand, has a general way of doing basic things that does not require special cmdlets to be installed or included with the deployed code.  I believe this is a step backwards in many respects.

Before anyone trashes me and says I just don't PowerShell, I must mention I have a long history of UNIX shell scripting behind me.  PowerShell is similar, obviously, but to me its not nearly as well implemented.

I do know that reality dictates that I will end up using PowerShell sooner or later - I just hope it evolves into a more "standard" replacement in the future.

Comment: Fair enough. I did a little UNIX shell scripting back in the late 1980's, so I can appreciate your perspective.